# React router prevent a ReDirect from firing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
 <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
         <Switch> 
          <Route path="/password-reset/:userId/:code" component={PasswordReset} />
          <Redirect from="/" strict exact to="/app/calculator" />
    </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
```

When the /password-reset is matched, the Redirect still kicks in.

How do I prevent the redirect to only match when the path is `example.com/`

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having a similar issue where the Switch is matching the route but still firing the Redirect later.